# How do you monitor Fabric.exe and other Service Fabric executables?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

There are several executables that run on the nodes that are part of the system services. I'd like to monitor them in some way to detect when there is an outage.

Wondering how others have done this?

Answer (score 0):

[Health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-generation-infra) [monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-health-introduction) is a built-in feature. Both the cluster and the workloads are monitored. This is possible because the cluster is running on multiple machines that can keep an eye on each other.

You can add [log analytics agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/log-analytics-agent) to get data from nodes into Azure Log Analytics.

Once telemetry is there, you can define query based [alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-unified-log) (like emails).